# Purple Lines at boot (possibly initramfs decoder error)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi, initramfs, gpt

What is happening is that when I try to boot normally, I get stuck in a black screen with some purple lines. Before I did anything it was showing a Initramfs decoding error and after looking it up, I managed to boot using recovery mode and change the the lz4 compressor for the gzip using the command "**sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf**" and changing it in the initrams file.
I also deleted the **"quiet splash"** terms on the GRUB file because it was suggested in some freeze screens problems. None of that resolved my problem and I my screen looks like this when I try to boot normally:Photo of the problem:
[image: .]

I still can boot using recovery mode, but it would be nice to make it work. Ay ideas? I'm using UEFI only to boot and my drives are formatted with the GPT partition method.

My Config:

- Ryzen 5 3500
- MSI B450I Gaming AC
- GTX 1660 Super
- 2x8 3200Mhz Corsair Vengeance RAM
- 500GB 850 EVO SSD (Using it to boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS AND Windows 10
  PRO)
- Corsair MP510 960GB (Only used on windows)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is now fixed and this is what I did:

1- installed the nvidia display driver using the command **"sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"**

This installed the latest tested drivers (It should be estable). That fixed the lines, but I got the famous purple screen of death. For those who don't know, that is a common problem in Ubuntu, Mint, Debian, etc. that happens when nvidia drivers are installed.

2- removed the display driver manager gdm3 using the terminal in the recovery mode

I boot into the recovery mode and opened the terminal there. Then I used the command **"sudo apt-get remove gdm3"** and rebooted.

3- removed the latest nvidia drivers, installed a older one and installed back the gdm3 display manager

Without a display manager, I could boot into the system normally, but now I have no GUI. I tried to use lightdm as as display driver instead of gdm3, but I got a different frozen screen. Then I uninstalled using the same method as before and booted into the system again.
The next step was to uninstall the nvidia drivers and to do that I used the commands **"sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')"** and **"sudo apt autoremove"**. Then instead of using the command **"sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"** again to install the latest drivers, I first used the command **"ubuntu-drivers"** to see what drivers were available and manually installed a older driver to see if it would work. for that I used the command **"sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx"** (xxx is the version that I chose. The latest version at the time of writing this is 455 and I installed version 450)
At last, I used the command **"sudo apt-get install gdm3"** to get a graphics back and it worked. No more lines or frozen screen.

Summary: I think that the purple lines were some kind of problem with the nouveau drivers, because as soon as I installed nvidia drivers, they were gone.
The purple screen was/is some problem with the driver version 455 and the display manager. Now I can boot normally into the system, but my second monitor isin't beeing recognized and the command **"nvidia-smi"** returns **" Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch"**... I will try to fix it now